# create-react-native-app could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, react-native

While trying to follow the "Getting Started" tutorial on React Native, I stumbled onto something that I believe is my fault, but I really can't find why (I'm a bit of a noob)

To create my first project, I'm told to use "create-react-native-app AwesomeProject". The script runs well at first

```
Creating a new React Native app in         
C:\Users\b.mathieu\.babun\cygwin\AwesomeProject.

Installing packages. This might take a couple minutes.
Installing react-native-scripts...

> dtrace-provider@0.8.3 install 
C:\Users\b.mathieu\.babun\cygwin\AwesomeProject\node_modules\dtrace-provider
> node scripts/install.js

> @exponent/ngrok@2.2.7 postinstall 
C:\Users\b.mathieu\.babun\cygwin\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@exponent\ngrok
> node ./postinstall.js

ngrok - binary unpacked.
```

Then comes a long tree, which I believe my project's tree. But then I get

```
npm WARN xdl@42.0.0 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-redux@5.0.5 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0-0 but none was installed.
Installing dependencies using npm...
```

And after that, it only gives me "npm ERR! ..." kind of lines, with git errors "could not read from remote repository"

It may be a dumb mistake, I really don't know. I'm on windows 10, and i tried using the "normal" cmd and babun, a linux-like terminal.

EDIT: It appears that babun thing was actually the problem. With the windows cmd, the problem that persists is:

```
npm WARN react-native-branch@2.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of react@>=15.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN lottie-react-native@1.1.1 requires a peer of react@>=15.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native-maps@0.15.2 requires a peer of react@>=15.4.0 but none was installed.
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy at all?

Comment: Also you can just do `npm install create-react-native-app -g` without needing any third party command line prompts. Then in your project directory just do `create-react-native-app myAwesomeApp` and it'll create.

Comment: yes it did work, sorry for the bother. I guess i'll live with those errors ! ^^